# Display fields in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a multi select query

```
SELECT C.CATEGORIES_NAME 
FROM CATEGORIES AS C 
WHERE CATEGORIES_ID = 1

UNION

SELECT L.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME 
FROM LOCATIONS_TYPE AS L 
WHERE LOCATION_TYPE_ID = 2 

UNION

SELECT S.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE 
FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS AS S 
WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 3
```

He gives me the result:

```
 CATEGORIES_NAME |
------------------
       free      |
       Plaza     |
      Mobiles    |
```

And I need to get this result:

```
 CATEGORIES_NAME | LOCATION_TYPE_NAME | SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE |
-----------------------------------------------------------
       free      |       Plaza        |      Mobiles      |
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is 1,2 and 3 are fixed? Or 4 can come as well?

Comment: @mkRabbani This is the record ID, I wrote for example 1, 2, 3. It can be integers.

Comment: It can be integers fine, but there will be 3 different integers only?

Comment: @mkRabbani Corrected the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to basically put `SELECT` before the queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT C.CATEGORIES_NAME 
        FROM CATEGORIES AS C 
        WHERE CATEGORIES_ID = 1
       ) as CATEGORIES_NAME,
       (SELECT L.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME 
        FROM LOCATIONS_TYPE AS L 
        WHERE LOCATION_TYPE_ID = 2
       ) as LOCATION_TYPE_NAME,
       (SELECT S.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME 
        FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS AS S 
        WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 3
       ) as LOCATION_TYPE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `crosstab()` - for reference you can check the details **[here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tablefunc.html)**

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
    SELECT *
    FROM crosstab(
        'SELECT C.CATEGORIES_NAME 
    FROM CATEGORIES AS C 
    WHERE CATEGORIES_ID = 1

    UNION

    SELECT L.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME 
    FROM LOCATIONS_TYPE AS L 
    WHERE LOCATION_TYPE_ID = 2 

    UNION

    SELECT S.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE 
    FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS AS S 
    WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_ID = 3'
    ) AS ct(CATEGORIES_NAME text, LOCATION_TYPE_NAME text, SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE text)
```

Comment: Error: `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @MegaRoks, you need to create using this command-  CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc. Add this and then check

Comment: @MegaRoks . . . This seems much more complicated than necessary.